# Google map api, uncaught error, marker.setMap not a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm building traffic jam app using MeteorJS 1.4.4.2 + ReactJS. I used atmosphere google map package before and 2 of popular google map npm package( istarkov and tomchentw ), those packages work fine but it does not has what i want, so instead i use google map api directly in order to get complete feature of it.

**I wanted to be able to remove selected marker on the map**

**Attemp:**

```
// Map functions in the same file as mapInit function

let addMarker = ( location )=> {

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: location,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        draggable: true

    }).addListener( 'click', ( e )=> removeMarkerOnClick( e ) );

    markers.push( marker );

};

let removeMarkerOnClick( marker )=> {

    let lat = marker.latLng.lat (),
        lng = marker.latLng.ln (),
        position = {};

    markers = markers.reduce(( new_markers, marker )=> {

        position = marker.f.position;

        position.lat() !== lat && position.lng() !== lng ?

            new_markers.push( marker ) : marker.setMap( null );

        return new_markers;

    }, markers);

}

window.initMap = () => {

    //.... body hidden

    map.addListener( 'click', ( e )=> addMarker( e.latLng ) );

}
```

**Error from client console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError:
    MapFunctions.jsx:74
    marker.setMap is not a function
     at http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=1f01aac45aac6af0dd009bc4623183b2511f62bf:419:20
at Array.reduce (native)
at removeMarkerOnClick (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=1f01aac45aac6af0dd009bc4623183b2511f62bf:413:23)
at _.Ge.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=1f01aac45aac6af0dd009bc4623183b2511f62bf:403:16)
at Object._.z.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1-fwP96l-_VAicaDGRNMmEU93TY4fcGs&libraries=places&callback=initMap:102:121)
at XT.<anonymous> (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/14/marker.js:19:348)
at _.pG._.z.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1-fwP96l-_VAicaDGRNMmEU93TY4fcGs&libraries=places&callback=initMap:102:121)
at _.pG.onclick (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1-fwP96l-_VAicaDGRNMmEU93TY4fcGs&libraries=places&callback=initMap:40:81)
at _.Bu._.z.trigger (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1-fwP96l-_VAicaDGRNMmEU93TY4fcGs&libraries=places&callback=initMap:102:121)
at _.Bu.<anonymous> (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1-fwP96l-_VAicaDGRNMmEU93TY4fcGs&libraries=places&callback=initMap:40:81)
```

**Solution Attempts:**

1. Using setOnMap( null ) also not work, same TypeError, setOnMap () not a function
2. Using marker.setVisibility( false ) also not work, same TypeError, ... not a function

I search around google for an hour and half and have not find anything yet, so please help and thanks very much for just spending your time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering if anyone is trying to find solution to this.
As when i try to search for Marker object, i try to use other example of marker, console log the marker object to check for differences, then i found that my marker object is in another top level object, so in order to access the setMap function, i have to go one lower level.
**Solution:**

```
let removeMarkerOnClick( marker )=> {

    let lat = marker.latLng.lat (),
        lng = marker.latLng.ln (),
        position = {};

    markers = markers.reduce(( new_markers, marker )=> {

        position = marker.f.position;

        position.lat() !== lat && position.lng() !== lng ?

        new_markers.push( marker ) : marker.f.setMap ( null ); // Change this line from marker.setMap( null ) to marker.f.setMap ( null )

        return new_markers;

    }, markers);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the event in the function call.

```
}).addListener( 'click', ( e )=> removeMarkerOnClick( e ) ); 

you should do:
}).addListener( 'click', ( e )=> removeMarkerOnClick( marker ) );
```

Comment: oh yes sorry, I did not see that coming, thanks you very much, i will fix it and report back to you as soon as possible

Comment: Hello bro, passing marker to it was just to get coordinate of it but it still does not solve the problem that causes marker.setMap() is not a function